# Warning: Using parfor without matlabpool in kmeans matlab

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, cluster-analysis, matlabpool

I would like to run the matlab kmeans using 4 lab

I open matlabpool

```
if ~matlabpool('size')
    matlabpool open 4; % Invokes workers
end
```

I set the option for the kmeans

```
stream = RandStream('mlfg6331_64');  % Random number stream
options = statset('UseParallel','always','UseSubstreams','always',...
    'Streams',stream);
```

Then I run the kmeans

```
            [clustersFirstHalf,fCentr] = kmeans(first_partition,cIdx,'Options',options,...
                'distance','sqEuclidean',...
                'emptyaction','singleton',...
                'replicates',37,...
                'start','cluster');
```

I get this warning message...

```
Warning: Using parfor without matlabpool. 
> In processParallelAndStreamOptions>parforValidateStreamOptions at 173
  In processParallelAndStreamOptions at 78
  In kmeans at 254
  In kmeans>loopBody at 360
  In smartForReduce>(parfor body) at 111
  In parallel_function>make_general_channel/channel_general at 879
  In remoteParallelFunction at 30
```

matlabpool is open...so it is very weird...

I'm using MATLAB R2012b on linux....
Can any of you help me?

Comment: Is this different from your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26474841/warning-using-parfor-without-matlabpool)? You are supposed to edit the original, not post a new one.  I'm going to flag as dup unless there is a substantive difference I'm not seeing.

Comment: @chappjc I think this is more clear...I've deleted the previous one...it was not answered yet

Comment: OK, but you should not do it that way.  Remember that when you edit your post it goes to the top of the list in the "Active" tab.

Comment: add the version of software you are using in the post.

Comment: @NKN MATLAB R2012b on linux...(edited the question)